# How to set ConTeXt in WinEdt 6.0?

Tags: installing, context, winedt

I'm very interesting ConTeXt but I don't know setting ConTeXt at WinEdt 6.0.

[image: ConTeXt]

You can see the screenshot, there is ConTeXt and
 “ **How to setting ConteXt at WinEdt 6.0 ?**”

Comment: @HarishKumar, ok

Comment: Hope you will upgrade to WinEdt 8.1 and use my add-on [`ConTeXt standalone`](http://www.winedt.org/Macros/LaTeX/ConTeXtStandalone.php)... Much better than adapting to WinEdt 6 where I don't know if there could be problems...

Comment: Yes, i will try to upgrade my WinEdt ... although i am very comfortable with WinEdt 6.0 :)

Comment: WinEdt 8.1 is far more functional than WinEdt 6 and has many new features. Anyway if you don't want want to try it, I'll write an answer to adapt it to WinEdt 6 (with no guarantee...)

Comment: @karlkoeller, Ok i'm very happy if you will write  an answer to adapt it to WinEdt 6.0 and  i can save my money :)

Comment: There's no upgrade fee to switch to WinEdt 8.1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I'm assuming that your ConTeXt setup is fully working (if it doesn't work from the command line don't expect to get it working from within WinEdt...).

I'm also assuming that you have one of the latest builds of WinEdt 6, being 20110315 the last (it may not work with earlier versions).

1. Copy the file `ConTeXt.edt` from the directory `%B\Exec\TeX` to the directory `%b\Exec\TeX` (check "Options" -> "Configuration Wizard" if you don't know the path of `%b` and `%B`).
2. Open the file `%b\Exec\TeX\ConTeXt.edt` in WinEdt.
3. Delete the line

   ```
     Assign(!"ConTeXt-Executable", !|context.exe|);
   ```
4. Replace the line

   ```
     LetReg(6,'%P');       // Startup Folder
   ```

   with

   ```
     LetReg(6,'%P');       // Startup Folder

     IfFileExists("%$('%!9-Executable');",!"Relax;",>
       !"Prompt('context.exe not found!',3,1);PopTagsandRegisters;Exit;");
     GetFilePath("%$('%!9-Executable');",5);
     GetFilePath("%!5",5);

     Assign("OLD-TEXMFCNF","%@('TEXMFCNF');");
     SetEnvVar("TEXMFCNF","");
     Assign("OLD-TEXMFOS","%@('TEXMFOS');");
     SetEnvVar("TEXMFOS","%!5");
     Assign("OLD-PATH","%@('PATH');");
     SetEnvVar("PATH","%@('TEXMFOS');\bin;%@('PATH');");
     Assign("OLD-SETUPTEX","%@('SETUPTEX');");
     SetEnvVar("SETUPTEX","done");
     Assign("OLD-CTXMINIMAL","%@('CTXMINIMAL');");
     SetEnvVar("CTXMINIMAL","yes");
   ```
5. Replace the lines

   ```
     Exe('%b\Exec\ExeCompiler.edt');
     PopTagsandRegisters;
   ```

   with

   ```
     Exe('%b\Exec\ExeCompiler.edt');

     SetEnvVar("TEXMFCNF","%$('OLD-TEXMFCNF');");
     Release("OLD-TEXMFCNF");
     SetEnvVar("TEXMFOS","%$('OLD-TEXMFOS');");
     Release("OLD-TEXMFOS");
     SetEnvVar("PATH","%$('OLD-PATH');");
     Release("OLD-PATH");
     SetEnvVar("SETUPTEX","%$('OLD-SETUPTEX');");
     Release("OLD-SETUPTEX");
     SetEnvVar("CTXMINIMAL","%$('OLD-CTXMINIMAL');");
     Release("OLD-CTXMINIMAL");

     PopTagsandRegisters;
   ```
6. Save the file.
7. Open the "Execution Modes" interface ("Options" menu) and insert the full path to `context.exe` in the `Executable` field (e.g. `C:\context\tex\texmf-mswin\bin\context.exe`). Then press OK.

   **NOTE:** this step is not needed if you've already inserted `context.exe` path in the environment variable `PATH`.

This should be enough.

Comment: what do you mean context.exe ? where is i can get context.exe? i am really dont know about context.exe

Comment: @HirWanto You're using MiKTeX that doesn't include ConTeXt. So you have to download ConTeXt standalone. See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone for downloads and instructions.

Comment: in the context only mtxrun.exe, rsync.exe and texlua.exe ,

Comment: @HirWanto, follow the instructions in that page... You have to launch `first-setup.bat` to download and setup ConTeXt.

Comment: so, i have to connet to internet to download and setup ConTeXt

Comment: @HirWanto Yes...

Comment: can i install context.exe via offline ?

Comment: @HirWanto I think not.

Comment: @karkoeller ,, thank for your add on Context at WinEdt 8 , i am succesfull compile my file  after follow your instruction.

Comment: @karkoeller, ok  your answer hepl me :)

Comment: @karkoeller , ok